# installing python-appindicator in 13.10

Tags: 13.10, apt, python, indicator

I'm trying to install `python-appindicator` in Ubuntu 13.10 but I'm receiving not found error:

```
E: unable to locate package python-appindicator
```

How can I install `python-appindicator` in 13.10 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`python-appindicator` is present in the ubuntu repository for 13.10. See [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python/python-appindicator).

So just run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-appindicator
```

Answer (score 2):

sometimes will face issues while running

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-appindicator

as like

> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    python-appindicator : Depends: libappindicator1 (= 12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

so in this case run

> sudo apt-get -f install

will resolve issue and will build dependencies packages

Greetings,
Pandy